# OpenSUSE ffmpeg mp4 output

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, opensuse, mp4

I keep getting the following error when I try to output an mp4 file with ffmpeg on OpenSUSE 42.1:

```
[NULL @ 0x7f2ef400b580] Requested output format 'mp4' is not a suitable output format
```

Is there something that I can install to fix this?

Comment: Which is the _commandline_ are you using? Try to see with `ffmpeg -formats | grep mp4` if it is supported on your system (it should be something like `E mp4             MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)`.

Comment: I used "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 720x480 -c:a copy output.mp4" but it seems to run after upgrading everything to the packman repo and rebooting but I can't check to see if the output works with VLC or anything else because just audio is played.

Comment: Ok sorry VLC also works after packman

Comment: You're welcome I just found  a similar issue [when creating thumbnail](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1786)... you were not the only one! Even if that time didn't sort the desired effect  ;)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to firstly add the packman repo with Yast and then install "k3b-codecs ffmpeg lame phonon-backend-vlc phonon4qt5-backend-vlc vlc-codecs". I also did a distribution upgrade just to get everything on the packman version and then did a reboot. Things only started working after the reboot so I'm not sure if dup is needed but if you already have a lot of those packages then it might just be.